# Cocos2d restart scene is blank but showing fps

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, cocos3d

I have a table view that lists the game maps I have. When I click on one, another storyboard loads containing a cocos2d scene.

The first time I load a scene, everything loads perfectly. However, the second time I try to load the scene (back from the navigation controller and clicking on the same map or another one), I get a blank screen showing the fps but nothing else.

here's my code in mapViewController (that contains the cocos2d)

```
    - (void)setupCocos3D { //called from viewDidLoad
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] setOpenGLView:openGLView];  


    ((ViewInterface*)[ViewInterface sharedViewInterface]).currentScene = [testScene scene];


    // Create the customized CC3Layer that supports 3D rendering.
    CC3Layer* cc3Layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];

    // Create the customized 3D scene and attach it to the layer.
    // Could also just create this inside the customer layer.


    cc3Layer.cc3Scene =  ((ViewInterface*)[ViewInterface sharedViewInterface]).currentScene;

    // Assign to a generic variable so we can uncomment options below to play with the capabilities
    CC3ControllableLayer* mainLayer = cc3Layer;

    mainLayer.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2048, 1320);

    [CCDirector sharedDirector].animationInterval = (1.0f / kAnimationFrameRate);
    [CCDirector sharedDirector].displayStats = YES;
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] enableRetinaDisplay: YES];

    ((ViewInterface*)[ViewInterface sharedViewInterface]).mainLayer = mainLayer;

    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene:((ViewInterface*)[ViewInterface sharedViewInterface]).mainLayer];
}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector] end];


}
```

It is really strange that I can see the fps therefore it seems that the only problem is either with the scene or the layer.

Comment: dont set the glview again, don't call director end, ie init director once and only do start/stopanimation

Comment: @LearnCocos2D When I do that, the view is simply blank, without the fps showing. I also made sure that the code in setupCocos3D is called only once.

Comment: perhaps you simply have no running scene?

Comment: @LearnCocos2D Well, the first time the scene runs perfectly fine, not the second...  here's my new code:   http://pastebin.com/TAXajq7g

Comment: also commenting the line :replaceScene in the else doesn't help...

Answer (score 0):

Is the scene being retained? Could it be getting released and not being re-created?

Comment: if you're not re-creating the scene, make sure you keep a strong reference to it.

Comment: unfortunately, that does not solve the problem... thanks for your time